# Things to do with a Mac Mini

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, mac-mini, television

So I just bought a Mac Mini.  Hooked it up to my TV and installed Boxee, Plex (kinda just using boxee tho), and EyeTV.

These are all cool, but I was wondering what else I can do!  It's a powerful little machine, so it'd be interesting to know what other functions people use it for.

Any suggestions & ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: I'm using mine as an actual computer. Comes with Lion. Installed things like Transmit, Photoshop, Aperture, iWork, Xcode. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

My old mini has all my DVDs ripped in iTunes and all my CDs, and many other audio-video files. But there is no limit to what you can do I guess. What was your plan when you bought it? Is it your only computer?

Comment: Actually no, I just wanted a better way to watch movies than my PS3.  And that's definitely mission accomplished.  My Macbook Pro is my main computer, so the Mini is used for nothing other than boxee atm really.

Answer (score 1):

[Server](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-lion-server/id444376097?mt=12) would be my killer app for a mini in the home.

Comment: Awesome! I should test this out!

Answer (score 1):

If you have other Macs, get OS X Server from the App Store and use it as a network Time Machine location. More reliable than backing up to a Time Capsule or the somewhat hack-y methods for backing up to non-OS X network shares.

Comment: Awesome idea.  My Time Machine Backups have been so lacking lately.  This could be cool!